# How does Naive Bayes differ on these two sets?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, data-mining, naive-bayes

This is likely a simple question (since it is from an introductory course) yet I'm getting myself in a muddle here:

*Suppose I used the Naive Bayes classifier on 5000 instances (each instance only has two classes: yes or no). Also, suppose there actually exists 250 yes instances, and 4750 no instances. Suppose further then that for a certain instance $A$, Naive Bayes predicts yes with probability 30% and no with probability 70%.*

The question is, if you resample this set (but do it with replacement) and get 1000 yes instances and 1000 no instances (so 2000 in total) and then run Naive Bayes again, how would the probabilities with regard to $A$ change?

To be honest quite confused, not sure how to start - any ideas?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: I've added something. Honestly even though I've read my course materials on this particular question I'm quite mystified.